# How to retrieve the Profile Card of the current Item?

Tags: marketing-definitions

Say I have a page item, that has the profile card set, how would I retrieve that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ProfileUtil` to retrieve the tracking field and profile data.

Example to retrieve the first profile set on the item:

```
var profiles = ProfileUtil.GetProfiles(item, out var trackingField);
return profiles?.FirstOrDefault()?.Name;
```